# 30-day grace period: flight leaves earlier than but arrives on the earliest date allowed

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, j1-visas

I have been granted a J-1 visa and would like to enter the US up to 30 days prior to the start of the course. Let's say the earliest day of entry would be April 1.

Do you think that I am allowed to take a plane from Europe that leaves on March 30, but arrives (first landing in the US) on April 1?

That might seem like pushing it, but it would be of great benefit for me.

Thank you for reading this.

Edit: Thank you for the comments! The "fair point" was useful as I might be flying via Dublin... :)

Comment: Yes, it's all about the arrival date, not the departure.

Comment: @phoog what if the departure is from a preclearance port?

Comment: @HankyPanky fair point.  In that case the departure may well have to be after the beginning of the grace period.  There are very few of those in Europe, however.